# Passing data to notification in laravel

Tags: laravel

Been stumped for awhile on how to pass two variables into a notification and have that notification include an action that contains a route with a token.  The use case is that my application allows users (called advisors here) to give access to other users.  If the added users are not already registered, their accounts will be created and they will receive an email with a token to complete their registration.

I have the following in my AddAdvisorsController:

```
 else {


        $newadvisor = Advisor::create($data);
        $newadvisor->save();

        $newadvisorID = $newadvisor->id;
        $newAdvisorEmail = $newadvisor->email;

        //create a token
        $token = Str::random(60);
        //email advisor and pass $token variable to notification
        $newadvisor->notify(new NewAdvisorNotification($token, $newAdvisorEmail));
```

I have the following in my NewAdvisorNotification:

```
<?php

namespace App\Notifications;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Messages\MailMessage;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notification;

class NewAdvisorNotification extends Notification
{
 use Queueable;

public $token;



/**
 * Create a new notification instance.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function __construct($token, $newAdvisorEmail)
{
    //
    $this->token = $token;
    $this->newAdvisorEmail = $newAdvisorEmail;


}

/**
 * Get the notification's delivery channels.
 *
 * @param  mixed  $notifiable
 * @return array
 */
public function via($notifiable)
{
    return ['mail'];
}

/**
 * Get the mail representation of the notification.
 *
 * @param  mixed  $notifiable
 * @return \Illuminate\Notifications\Messages\MailMessage
 */
public function toMail($notifiable)
{
    return (new MailMessage)
                ->line('You are receiving this email because we received a new account request for your email.')
                ->action('Notification Action', route('new.advisor', [$this->token, $this->newAdvisorEmail]))
                // ->action('Notification Action', route('advisor/new-account/{{ $token }}/{newAdvisorEmail}'))
                ->line('If you did not request a password reset, no further action is required.');
}

/**
 * Get the array representation of the notification.
 *
 * @param  mixed  $notifiable
 * @return array
 */
public function toArray($notifiable)
{
    return [
        //
    ];
}
```

}

The new user is getting created properly in the database, but I get an error saying:

Missing required parameters for [Route: update.advisor] [URI: advisor/new-account/{token}/{newAdvisorEmail}]. (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\HealthHub\resources\views\auth\new-accounts\advisor-new-account.blade.php)

I have the following routes:

```
    Route::get('/advisor/new-account/{token}/{newAdvisorEmail}', 'NewAdvisorController@showNewAccountForm')->name('new.advisor');
Route::post('/advisor/new-account/{token}/{newAdvisorEmail}', 'NewAdvisorController@updateNewAccount')->name('update.advisor');
```

});

I think my code is having errors with this line:

```
                ->action('Notification Action', route('new.advisor', [$this->token, $this->newAdvisorEmail]))
```

However, I am not sure how to fix it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You error clearly states you are missing parameters for your route. The way to specify route parameters is by name, so declare an associate array with the route parameter name as the key.

```
 ->action('Notification Action', route('new.advisor', ['token' => $this->token, 'newAdvisorEmail' => $this->newAdvisorEmail,]))
```